# Dynamically set text on AjaxCheckBox in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket-6

I'm changing an existing Wicket page to set its text and appearance in Java, based on conditions when the user opens the page. Most of the components are playing nicely with updating the model, but I'm stuck on the AjaxCheckBox.

The code to instantiate the checkbox is roughly:

```
checkBox = new AjaxCheckBox("checkbox", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(this, "agreed")) {
  @Override
  protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    target.add(installButton);}
  };
add(checkBox);
```

and the Wicket markup is:

```
<div style="margin: 1em;">
    <input type="checkbox" wicket:id="checkbox">
    <wicket:message key="Config.Agree"/>
    </input><br/>
    <button wicket:id="installButton"><span wicket:id="buttonText"/></button><br/>
</div>
```

Not having any luck taking out the wicket:message line and setting the text in Java, and Google is failing me. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like posting a question on SO to get the answer from our resident Wicket guru...

The answer was to change the wicket:message to a span, tie the span to a label, and add the label as a child of the checkbox.

New Wicket markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" wicket:id="checkbox">
<span wicket:id="checkboxText">&nbsp;</span>
</input><br/>
```

New Java code:

```
Model checkboxTextModel = Model.of("Default text");
Label checkboxText = new Label("checkboxText", checkboxTextModel);
checkBox = new AjaxCheckBox("checkbox", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(this, "agreed")) {
  @Override
  protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    target.add(installButton);
  }
};
checkBox.add(checkboxText);
add(checkBox);
```

Then I can change the text using checkboxTextModel.setObject("my new string"); later on.

Comment: This is an invalid HTML. <input> cannot have child elements. You may want to check HTML <label> and its usages.